# What's the difference between the terms "Shell" and "Bash"?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

What is the the difference between "Shell" and "Bash" and what do these terms mean?

As far as I know, there is no difference. But I've seen many books about "Shell" and others about "Bash"!

So in case I want to work with the Terminal on Mac OS X and write some bash scripts, I'm wondering which kind of books I should go for.

Comment: It is a class versus instance distinction.

Comment: Interesting reading material: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con

Comment: the first shell was written by a guy called Bourne.  BASH is an acronym for 'Boune Again Shell'.  It is important to have fun!

Comment: [What is the differences of these concepts(Shell, Terminal, Console and Command-line) in Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/795950/241386)

Answer (score 34):

A "[shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29)" is any software that provides an interface to an operating system. For instance, [explorer.exe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell) is the default shell in Windows (though [alternatives exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell_replacement)), and on OS X [Finder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_%28software%29) provides much of the same functionality. On Linux/*nix, the shell could be part of the desktop environment (like [Gnome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) or [KDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE)), or can be a separate software component sitting on top of it (like [Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28user_interface%29) or [Cinnamon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_%28user_interface%29)).

The above examples are all graphical shells that use a combination of windows, menus, icons and other such elements to provide a graphical user interface (GUI) that can be interacted with using the mouse cursor. However, in the context of software like Bash, or writing scripts, "shell" is usually taken to mean a command-line interpreter, which performs largely the same duties as a graphical shell, except is entirely text-based.

[Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) is a specific example of a command-line shell, and is probably one of the most well-known ones, being the default in many Linux distributions as well as OS X. It was designed as a replacement for the [Bourne shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) (Bash stands for "Bourne again shell"), one of the first [Unix shells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell).

Examples of command-line shells on Windows include [cmd.exe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) (aka Command Prompt) and [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell).

Comment: Finder isn't usually called a shell on OS X. Most of the GUI and window management features are handled by other processes.

Comment: @LauriRanta [Wikipedia seems to disagree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software)). Regardless of whether or not it has help from other processes, its job is to enable the user to interact with the underlying OS through a GUI, and thus it fits the description of a graphical shell.

Comment: I guess the term graphical shell can also apply to file management applications. But it's not generally used on OS X, and Finder is more like Nautilus than the Windows shell or Unity.

Comment: @LauriRanta: quick quiz, what's the icon of Nautilus?

Comment: @LauriRanta Wouldn't Dock be a better candidate for a shell? Launching programs and opening documents, Expose/Spaces/Mission Control, AFAIK Launchpad and the task switcher as well are all Dock features.

Comment: Finder is hardly a shell. You know anyone can edit Wikipedia right?

Comment: @KorayTugay I do. I also know anyone can argue over semantics ;)

Comment: I guess you can call Internet Explorer a shell as well.

Comment: Why do you call Gnome or KDE a shell for *nix but Finder for OS X? What is X Window System then? Where does it stand in regard to Finder?

Answer (score 15):

Bash is one of several shells.

A shell on a Unix or Unix-like system like OSX or Linux is a application program that provides a command-line interface to the operating system, allowing you to type commands and run them.  There are a number of different shells to choose from but they all provide filename wildcarding, piping, here documents, command substitution, variables and control structures for condition-testing and iteration.

The original Unix shell was the [Bourne shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell), sh, written by Stephen Bourne at Bell Labs.  Then came the [C shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell), written by Bill Joy at Berkeley, since updated as [tcsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh).  Other shells include the [Korn shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell), ksh, written by David Korn, also at Bell Labs, and [bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), the "Bourne again shell", written by Brian Fox for the GNU project as a free replacement for sh.

Today, bash is probably the most popular Unix shell but a lot of people (me included) still prefer the C shell based on (what to some of us seems like) its nicer syntax.  Basically, it's a matter of taste, so I recommend reading the Wikipedia articles I've linked to help you get started.

Comment: Shells are not necessarily command-line based, there are many graphical shells as well, e.g. Nautilus, Windows Explorer, Finder, etc. The essential point for shell is it is a wrapper/user interface/shell around core OS functionalities/system calls, i.e. shells provides management of resources (e.g. file management) and management of processes.

Comment: @LieRyan those are not shells, they are file managers. Shells allow integrated command/script interpreters to run within them. See my answer. Just being able to run a program from a file manager doesn't make it a shell.

Comment: @BillR: You ought to inform the Gnome Shell guys of your definition.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Lie Ryan and paradroid, that graphical shells are now considered shells.  I'm as invested in the command line paradigm as anyone and resisted accepting graphical shells as shells through the 90s.  But with all the control panel widgets and whatnot in a modern graphical shell, I now agree the common usage is to call them shells and that that usage is correct.  They match the definition of a shell, a relatively thin user interface layer around the underlying OS.  Graphical shells are weaker on how anyone would script anything but lots of users don't care about that.

Answer (score 6):

The term 'shell' is well named. It is literally a shell around the O/S allowing the user to interact with the computer. When it was originally conceived there were very little if any graphical user interfaces (no windows :( ). Everything was done on the command line. But even the command line needed a place to live. It lived, and still does, in a shell.

In simple terms, in order for the command line to be useful it needed instructions that it could call. So programs were made to run inside the shell for the command line to use. The programs were grouped tightly in their own packages, and intended to work together. They include programs like "ls" and "grep", "ps", "sed", etc. They also include file redirection commands like ">" and "<" and pipes ("|"). More importantly they also include programming constructs like conditional operations (if, then, else, for loops, while loops, ways to check the status returned when you run a statement (e.g. if you run "ls" did it find anything?), thing like that). These are the foundations of more complex command line (shell) scripts, and in fact is what the command line interpreter is.

When someone uses the term 'Bash Shell' they are talking about a command line interpreter called 'Bash' that runs in the O/S shell. You could think of it as being short for 'Bash Shell Interpreter'. There are other interpreters like Bourne (Bash is a 'new and improved Bourne Shell and it is short for Bourne Again Shell). There is also the C-Shell, the K-Shell (favoured by many who write complex shell scripts), and other GNU variants. Over the years it has become customary to refer to the particular command line interpreter you are using as the shell because one can't be used without the other. But the reality is that they are different.

As to why they are properly known as command line interpreters and not as the actual shell: it is because they live in the shell and interpret all commands as if they were running in a program. And the shell doesn't care what interpreter you run in it, as long as it meets the correct standards.

And as to why they are called interpreters, it is because they are really interpreters. Even if you are not explicitly running a script (and a script is really just a text file of commands you create so that you can execute the same commands over and over without having to type them in again). For example, take the humble 'ls' command. When you run it, it returns a list of files. But how it runs is more important to your question: It actually runs inside the context of the command line interpreter, even if you just run what appears to be a simple one off command. That is, it runs as if it were a statement in part of a bigger program. It runs as if it were in a shell script script file without actually being in a shell script file. An anonymous shell script file as it were.

Anything you run on the command line has this in common (whether it be a single command like 'ls' or a script file full of commands and iterators and conditional statements): it is all processed by the command line interpreter; be it Bash, C-Shell, K-Shell (default on AIX btw).

To see what I mean, make a directory 'test':

```
mkdir test
```

Enter it and run the folowing commands

```
grep hello *
```

You will get some sort of response like 'no such file or directory'. Now enter the command

```
echo $?
```

($? says, tell me what you found in cryptic computer speak.) You should see it return a number (it should be) '2'. That is the return code from grep that means 'no such file or directory'. Now run the following:

```
echo hello > hello.txt
grep hello *
echo $?
```

You will see the file 'hello.txt' returned from the initial grep command and should now see the 'echo $?' return the number '0' meaning it actually found something.

Even if these seemingly one off commands are run, the command line interpreter acts like they are part of a larger program and keeps track of their return values. That is why if you forget the * at the end of the grep command it doesn't return. It is knows the statement is incomplete and expects more input. After all you could conceivably be going to ask it to grep the results of some loop which is perfectly legal to write and run on the command line.

Bottom line is the shell is the shell, and the interpreter (whatever the name of the one you use, 'Bash', k-shell, etc.) are different. But often they are used interchangeably, because at any given instant they are completely tied together.

Answer (score 2):

Shell is a text based user interface.

Bash is a type of shell.

Comment: What is a "test based user interface"? Also it would be nice to expand your answer a little.. As you can see from the other answers, it always helps to give more context.

Comment: Sorry. Text-based user interface.

How would you like for me to expound upon that? A shell is your command line way of interacting with the operating systems kernel. The Shell interprets your commands and relays them to the machine which then, in turn, performs the necessary operations relevant to the command you've given?

Without a 500 page manual it's difficult to effectively expound on this ambiguous question. The effort of the answer fit the effort of the question. This question is apples to oranges.

Comment: If you think a question shows now effort that doesn't automatically mean you shouldn't put effort in an answer to it. Your answer, in comparison to the others, lacks a little detail. Of course it's up to you to add that.

Comment: I appreciate the correction and lesson in personal responsibility. Thank you for protecting those who aren't willing to put in the effort from those who do. I am totally out of line forgetting how much I owed the poster.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` is one of the `shell` family, but there's plenty of other shells.

By example, on [Minix3](http://www.minix3.org/), there's the `ash` shell, it doesn't support associative arrays like `bash4`.

The [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard is an attempt to make a portable API between differents shells and OSes.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Bourne_shell_compatible

Answer (score 1):

`bash` is one of the many shells that exist.

All shells have their similarities and differences. For example a script written in bash, might be fully or largely compatible with another shell (for example [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsh)).

Due to the fact that `bash` is very widespread, it is often implied that a script is compatible with it.

If you're looking to buy a book, buy one written specifically for the shell you intend to use.
It would be a good idea to read up on their differences before spending money though.